# Dynamic Linked Label cannot open a website

Tags: c#

I recently started to work with dynamic components, and it worked fine until I started with dynamic linked label. So here's my Problem:  I want to open a website through a label link but every time I try to do that, it happens to break the program and give me the error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

```
 private void CreateDynamicLinkedLabel() {
        LinkLabel mylinklab = new LinkLabel();
        mylinklab.Text = "asdasdasda";
        mylinklab.AutoSize = true;
        mylinklab.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(mylinklab_Clicked);
        Controls.Add(mylinklab);
    }

    private void mylinklab_Clicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e) {
        Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
    private void mylinklab_Clicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e) {
        Process.Start("chrome.exe","http://www.google.com");
    }
```

i even included `using System.Diagnostics;`
I tried to figure out why it wont work, but every Youtube Video looks like my code.
Maybe there is another way to open a link, but i cant figure it out.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are targeting net core 3+. In this case you need to explicitly set `UseShellExecute=true` to get behaviour as it was in net framework. In net core there was a breaking changes in the default options for new process. More details https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17938

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = url,
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start (psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your method in your code:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = url, UseShellExecute = true });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).